# Financial gift or nasty surprise

Tags: united-kingdom, banking, international-transfer, scams

If a friend from the U.K. is wanting to give me a large amount of money, why would they need my signature? They haven't requested any bank account details, but why would I need to sign something to receive money? Is there a way of transferring money into my name without it going to a bank account or could this be a scam?

Comment: Judging from your comments, this is unambiguously a scam. Do not get involved.

Comment: The obvious question is "What are they asking you to sign?". You've read it, right?

Answer (score 10):

It's got every sign of a scam. Signatures are needed on contracts, so you should only place them on below one. Free money sounds too good to be true. Money evading banks is a typical sign of money laundering; why are they trying to avoid paper trails?

The normal way to gift money is to just hand it over or pay it to a bank account. If anything, you sign a tax declaration, but you would send that to the taxman yourself.

Comment: Actually they said they need an account, but to transfer from the U.K. to Australia that I need to authorise it? I was told it was to verify that I am who I say I am, and that my friend won't be seen as trying to launder money or avoid paying taxes?

Comment: Who are "they" anyway? And how well do you know this friend? Furthermore, what exactly would you authorise, and to whom? It's not a big deal if your friend asks you to download a form from the official government/tax website from either the UK or Australian government, sign that and in general follow the instructions given for that form. In general, if anyone claims "government regulations", ask them to be specific and verify with an independent source.

Comment: I believe that is the form they are referencing. I actually thought to ask my accountant to handle it, but wasn't sure if it would make any difference. I know this friend very well. The money is being gifted to help another friend who is an ambassador for a charity. I was just being a bit cautious about handing over account details as you hear about things like identity theft. Not that i would think this friend would do this, but I don't trust anyone.

Comment: That's another TWO warning signs: "gifting" money which you're supposed to forward, and invoking a charity. Tell your friend to gift the money directly to the charity at hand, without involving you or the ambassador of that charity. (A real charity will have a designated person to handle donations, whereas an ambassador handles PR for a charity)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I guess they can benefit from a nice tax deduction too then?

Comment: That would be unlikely since they aren't donating to a charity but to you. They probably would get a tax deduction if they donated straight to charity, so that's yet another warning sign.

Comment: That is what i meant. If they donate direct to the charity they could get a tax deduction. The charity is for domestic violence and this ambassador is a personal friend. The friend from the U.K. was also wanting her to benefit, hence why he was wanting to gift to me to split some between the charity and towards my friend. But i think i will tell him to just donate direct to the charity.

Comment: Why would a 'friend' need to verify who you are? If they don't know you that well, they aren't a friend.

Comment: They aren't verifying who I am. He was explaining that due to current laws in the U.K. that the government needs my signature to verify the information I supply is true and correct. This is to comply with current laws to verify that he isn't trying to avoid paying tax or money laundering etc. I was simply trying to work out why my signature would be required. If you read the above it's not my identity or friendship that is in question, simply a matter of ascertaining why it would be needed.

Comment: The UK government wouldn't need your signature as much as they'd need you to sign a specific form. Check the form yourself with the UK government, and in particular check whether you're supposed to submit it directly to the UK government.